# Replaying sequences played after pressing the continue button in Heart of the Swarm

Tags: starcraft-2

In Heart of the Swarm, after the continue button is clicked, sometimes small sequences are played where Kerrigan utters commands to her broodmothers to attack certain planets.

Is there any way to see them again without replaying the whole campaign ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cheat code: ***eyeofsauron*** can be used to watch all cinematics and you can skip past the ones that you aren't interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you have a save file right before that part. If it JUST happened, you can try to reload an auto-save of the level right before you completed it.

Only cinematics are available for replaying.